# It's possible to add a Key to a layout of the keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I want to add a key to a layout.

I have an en-US keyboard layout, and I want to add this letter "ñ" and this one "Ñ" to the N key. It's possible to add this key by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (ñ) and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (Ñ)??

I found apps like sharpkeys or keytweak, but they don't be able to do this.

Comment: I feel like AutoHotKey could.

Comment: What's wrong with using the US International Keyboard layout? It already allows you to type those 2 characters. See [Typing Special Characters in Windows 10 – Instructional Design & Technology](http://social.rollins.edu/wpsites/idt/faqs-how-tos/facultystaff/foliotek-faculty/adding-an-international-keyboard-layout-to-type-special-characters-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need one.. I normally use Alt + 1,6,4 (on numpad) -> ñ  & Alt + 1,6,4 (on numpad) -> Ñ for my special character needs.

If I'm lazy, I'll do Windows + R > charmap. [ you can see the keyboard shortcut at the bottom right for each special character ] ( :

example reference (I don't really use this one.. but the content are the same) : [link](https://tools.oratory.com/altcodes.html)